# JDO and app engine: defining the primary key as subclass member

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have the following classes:

```
@PersistenceCapable
class Store {

  // ???
  User admin;
  ...

  @Persistent
  @Element(dependent = true)
  List<Item> items;

}

@PersistenceCapable
class User {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent
  String email;

}

@PersistenceCapable
class Item {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent
  String itemCode;

  ...

}
```

I want to make admin.email the primary key of Store entities.
Is this possible with JDO on app engine? How should I proceed?

Thank you for your help,

John Goche

Answer (score 0):

You can make "admin" the PK simply by marking it as PK and defining a PK class for Store, following the DataNucleus docs for "Compound Identity" (and since admin.email is the PK of User then thats the same)

Comment: I've had a look at http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/orm/compound_identity.html but I am still somewhat puzzled. Do I need to create an inner static class named PK? And how do I do this with annotations instead of XML. The relationship between Store and User is 1-1 in my particular case.

Comment: You create a PK class ... whether it is inner, or separate class is up to you. And what has annotations got to do with the PK Class ? you simply mark the "objectid-class" of the Store class as this PK class

Comment: Sorry if I do not completely follow, would you be able to post some code? What exactly is a PK class?

Comment: The page you refer to has an example, and the "PK class" I refer to is, in that case, the class called "PK" ;-) Account.PK for example

Comment: I may be thick but the explanation on the given page points to http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/orm/one_to_one.html which has this @Column(name="USER_ID") field which only seems to apply to RDBMS, but I need to use JDO for google's bigtable datastore which presumably does not use tables? I don't have a grip on how bigtable works so I cannot figure out what the PK code of JDO is doing. Any help sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Why on earth do I need a PK class? I want admin.email to be the PK. It is of class String. Why need a separate class called PK?

Comment: You are *not* making "admin.email" as the PK, you are making "admin" as the PK. To use compound id you need it ... so just COPY that example and change the names of the fields/classes.

Comment: Fair enough, I could just copy the example, but I would like to understand what the PK class that would be added to my code actually does and how, say in terms of the low-level datastore. Any ideas?